# how to loop over directories in python

Tags: python, loops, directory

I have a big list of text files in a folder, and I want to loop over all those file, copy the content of each one and paste in another specific text file that will contain all the looped files content.

This is my beginning of the program:

```
path = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\ak\Desktop\Nouveau dossier (2)') 
final_file = open(r'C:\Users\ak\Desktop\final_file.txt')

for i in path:
   f = open(i, 'r')
```

Then I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 2, in
>   
>       f= open('i','r') FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'i'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use `join` to get the full path. It also looks like in your actual code you have quotes around your variable, `i`. You should also be using a context manager (`with`) to save having to remember to close the file. This is how I would do it:

```
for i in path:
    with open(os.path.join(path, i), 'r') as f:
        # do something with the file
```